# Pipe a stream to s3.upload()

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, node-streams

I'm currently making use of a node.js plugin called [s3-upload-stream](https://github.com/nathanpeck/s3-upload-stream) to stream very large files to Amazon S3. It uses the multipart API and for the most part it works very well.

However, this module is showing its age and I've already had to make modifications to it (the author has deprecated it as well).  Today I ran into another issue with Amazon, and I would really like to take the author's recommendation and start using the official aws-sdk to accomplish my uploads.

BUT.

The official SDK does not seem to support piping to `s3.upload()`.  The nature of s3.upload is that you have to pass the readable stream as an argument to the S3 constructor.

I have roughly 120+ user code modules that do various file processing, and they are agnostic to the final destination of their output. The engine hands them a pipeable writeable output stream, and they pipe to it.  I cannot hand them an `AWS.S3` object and ask them to call `upload()` on it without adding code to all the modules.  The reason I used `s3-upload-stream` was because it supported piping.

Is there a way to make aws-sdk `s3.upload()` something I can pipe the stream to?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Wrap the S3 `upload()` function with the node.js `stream.PassThrough()` stream.

Here's an example:

```
inputStream
  .pipe(uploadFromStream(s3));

function uploadFromStream(s3) {
  var pass = new stream.PassThrough();

  var params = {Bucket: BUCKET, Key: KEY, Body: pass};
  s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log(err, data);
  });

  return pass;
}
```

Comment: Great, this solved my very ugly hack =-) Can you explain what the stream.PassThrough() actually does?

Comment: Does your PassThrough stream close when you do this? I'm having a heck of a time propegating the close in s3.upload to hit my PassThrough stream.

Comment: the size of the uploaded file is 0 byte. If I pipe the same data from source stream to file system all works good. Any idea?

Comment: @lawrence I did. but right now I don't Remember how :( the only thing that I remember is that the problem was related to some params passed to the upload method. check bucket name and key maybe.

Comment: A passthrough stream will take bytes written to it and output them. This lets you return a writable stream that aws-sdk will read from as you write to it. I'd also return the response object from s3.upload() because otherwise you can't ensure the upload completes.

Comment: I tried this approach, my uploaded file is also 0 bytes. Could anybody help me with that?

Comment: I'm also getting 0 byte file on S3. - This solution is incomplete? @CaseyBenko

Comment: I saw 0 bytes as well when doing this through an Express route. I changed the content-type to text/plain and it works fine.

Comment: Isn't this just the same as passing the readable stream to Body but with more code? The AWS SDK is still going to call read() on the PassThrough stream so there's no true piping all the way to S3. The only difference is there's an extra stream in the middle.

Comment: from where the `s3` param inside pipe and `stream` are coming from?

Answer (score 180):

A bit late answer, it might help someone else hopefully. You can return both writeable stream and the promise, so you can get response data when the upload finishes.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const stream = require('stream');

const uploadStream = ({ Bucket, Key }) => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  const pass = new stream.PassThrough();
  return {
    writeStream: pass,
    promise: s3.upload({ Bucket, Key, Body: pass }).promise(),
  };
}
```

And you can use the function as follows:

```
const { writeStream, promise } = uploadStream({Bucket: 'yourbucket', Key: 'yourfile.mp4'});
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/yourfile.mp4');

const pipeline = readStream.pipe(writeStream);
```

Now you can either check promise:

```
promise.then(() => {
  console.log('upload completed successfully');
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('upload failed.', err.message);
});
```

Or using async/await:

```
try {
    await promise;
    console.log('upload completed successfully');
} catch (error) {
    console.log('upload failed.', error.message);
}
```

Or as `stream.pipe()` returns stream.Writable, the destination (writeStream variable above), allowing for a chain of pipes, we can also use its events:

```
 pipeline.on('close', () => {
   console.log('upload successful');
 });
 pipeline.on('error', (err) => {
   console.log('upload failed', err.message)
 });
```

Comment: It looks great, but on my side I am getting this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62330721/unsupported-body-payload-object-when-trying-to-upload-to-amazon-s3-using-stream

Comment: I call this in an async function, so I use `await Promise`.  Works for me thank you - this was such a huge and unexpected issue for me.

Comment: This is nice, and we've used it, but unfortunately it seems that with AWS SDK v3 it's no longer possible to return the "upload" and `pass` as it returns `TypeError: dest.on is not a function", "at Readable.pipe (node:internal/streams/readable:692:8)"`

Answer (score 65):

In the accepted answer, the function ends before the upload is complete, and thus, it's incorrect. The code below pipes correctly from a readable stream.

[Upload reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property)

```
async function uploadReadableStream(stream) {
  const params = {Bucket: bucket, Key: key, Body: stream};
  return s3.upload(params).promise();
}

async function upload() {
  const readable = getSomeReadableStream();
  const results = await uploadReadableStream(readable);
  console.log('upload complete', results);
}
```

You can also go a step further and output progress info using `ManagedUpload` as such:

```
const manager = s3.upload(params);
manager.on('httpUploadProgress', (progress) => {
  console.log('progress', progress) // { loaded: 4915, total: 192915, part: 1, key: 'foo.jpg' }
});
```

[ManagedUpload reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html)

[A list of available events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#httpUploadProgress-event)

Comment: aws-sdk now offers promises built into 2.3.0+, so you don't have to lift them anymore. s3.upload(params).promise().then(data => data).catch(error => error);

Comment: @DBrown Thanks for the pointer! I've updated the answer, accordingly.

Comment: @tsuz, trying to implement your solution give me an error: `TypeError: dest.on is not a function`, any idea why?

Comment: What is `dest.on`? Can you show an example? @FireBrand

Comment: @tsuz I think it was a node issue, i ended up using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/streaming-s3  , that gave me what i needed, thanks.

Comment: This says the accepted answer is incomplete but it doesn't work with piping to s3.upload as indicated in @Womp's updated post. It would be very helpful if this answer was updated to take the piped output of something else!

Comment: without the `manager.on("httpUploadProgress" ....` line, the steam upload never starts / finishes;  How can I start or finish the stream upload without listening to `httpUploadProgress` and without printing the progress?

Answer (score 43):

I think it's worth updating the answer for AWS SDK v3 :).

S3 Client doesn't have `upload` function anymore and the `@aws-sdk/lib-storage`  package is suggested instead as per https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/lib/lib-storage/README.md

Hence the resulting snippet should look like this:

```
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { Upload } from '@aws-sdk/lib-storage';
const stream = require('stream');

...

const client = new S3Client({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
  region: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
});

...

async function uploadStream(readableStream) {

  const Key = 'filename.pdf'; 
  const Bucket = 'bucket-name';
  const passThroughStream = new stream.PassThrough();

  let res;

  try {
    const parallelUploads3 = new Upload({
      client,
      params: {
        Bucket,
        Key,
        Body: passThroughStream,
        ACL:'public-read',
      },
      queueSize: 4,
      partSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
      leavePartsOnError: false,
    });

    readableStream.pipe(passThroughStream);
    res = await parallelUploads3.done();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  return res;
}
```

Comment: The real MVP right here!
You could also just set `Body: readableStream`

Comment: Un-effing-believable that `Upload` isn't part of the `@aws-sdk/client-s3` library, nor is it documented anywhere on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_s3_code_examples.html. I wasted so much time screwing around with `PutObjectCommand` which is the wrong thing to use in most cases. What the hell AWS.

Comment: ideas why i get: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object`

Answer (score 12):

None of the answers worked for me because I wanted to:

- Pipe into `s3.upload()`
- Pipe the result of `s3.upload()` into another stream

The accepted answer doesn't do the latter. The others rely on the promise api, which is cumbersome to work when working with stream pipes.

This is my modification of the accepted answer.

```js
const s3 = new S3();

function writeToS3({Key, Bucket}) {
  const Body = new stream.PassThrough();

  s3.upload({
    Body,
    Key,
    Bucket: process.env.adpBucket
  })
   .on('httpUploadProgress', progress => {
       console.log('progress', progress);
   })
   .send((err, data) => {
     if (err) {
       Body.destroy(err);
     } else {
       console.log(`File uploaded and available at ${data.Location}`);
       Body.destroy();
     }
  });

  return Body;
}

const pipeline = myReadableStream.pipe(writeToS3({Key, Bucket});

pipeline.on('close', () => {
  // upload finished, do something else
})
pipeline.on('error', () => {
  // upload wasn't successful. Handle it
})
```

Comment: It looks great, but on my side I am getting this error stackoverflow.com/questions/62330721/…

Comment: without the `.on("httpUploadProgress" ....` line, the steam upload never starts / finishes;  How can I start or finish the stream upload without listening to `httpUploadProgress` and without printing the progress?

Answer (score 9):

Type Script solution: 
This example uses:

```
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";
import * as fsExtra from "fs-extra";
import * as zlib from "zlib";
import * as stream from "stream";
```

And async function:

```
public async saveFile(filePath: string, s3Bucket: AWS.S3, key: string, bucketName: string): Promise<boolean> { 

         const uploadStream = (S3: AWS.S3, Bucket: string, Key: string) => {
            const passT = new stream.PassThrough();
            return {
              writeStream: passT,
              promise: S3.upload({ Bucket, Key, Body: passT }).promise(),
            };
          };
        const { writeStream, promise } = uploadStream(s3Bucket, bucketName, key);
        fsExtra.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(writeStream);     //  NOTE: Addition You can compress to zip by  .pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(writeStream)
        let output = true;
        await promise.catch((reason)=> { output = false; console.log(reason);});
        return output;
}
```

Call this method somewhere like:

```
let result = await saveFileToS3(testFilePath, someS3Bucket, someKey, someBucketName);
```

Comment: Hi @dzole vladimirov .... It was just too good. Thank you so much. Regards. It helped me resolve the concern of uploading a file to s3 bucket

Answer (score 7):

Following the other answers and using the latest AWS SDK for Node.js, there's a much cleaner and simpler solution since the s3 upload() function accepts a stream, using await syntax and S3's promise:

```
var model = await s3Client.upload({
    Bucket : bucket,
    Key : key,
    ContentType : yourContentType,
    Body : fs.createReadStream(path-to-file)
}).promise();
```

Comment: This works for the specific use-case of "reading a very large file" the author mentioned, but the other answers are still valid if you are using streams outside the context of a file (for example trying to write a mongo cursor stream to s3 where you still need to use a PassThrough stream + pipe)

Answer (score 6):

The thing here to note in the most accepted answer above is that:
You need to return the pass in the function if you are using pipe like,

`fs.createReadStream(<filePath>).pipe(anyUploadFunction())`

```
function anyUploadFunction () { 
 let pass = new stream.PassThrough();
 return pass // <- Returning this pass is important for the stream to understand where it needs to write to.
}
```

Otherwise it will silently move onto next without throwing an error or will throw an error of `TypeError: dest.on is not a function` depending upon how you have written the function

Answer (score 5):

If it helps anyone I was able to stream from the client to s3 successfully:

https://gist.github.com/mattlockyer/532291b6194f6d9ca40cb82564db9d2a

The serverside code assumes `req` is a stream object, in my case it was sent from the client with file info set in the headers.

```
const fileUploadStream = (req, res) => {
  //get "body" args from header
  const { id, fn } = JSON.parse(req.get('body'));
  const Key = id + '/' + fn; //upload to s3 folder "id" with filename === fn
  const params = {
    Key,
    Bucket: bucketName, //set somewhere
    Body: req, //req is a stream
  };
  s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send('Error Uploading Data: ' + JSON.stringify(err) + '\n' + JSON.stringify(err.stack));
    } else {
      res.send(Key);
    }
  });
};
```

Yes it breaks convention but if you look at the gist it's much cleaner than anything else I found using multer, busboy etc...

+1 for pragmatism and thanks to @SalehenRahman for his help.

Comment: multer, busboy handle multipart/form-data uploads. req as a stream works when client sends a buffer as body from XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: To clarify, the upload is being performed from the back end not the client right?

Comment: Yes it's "piping" the stream, ON the backend, but it came from a frontend

Answer (score 5):

For those complaining that the when they use the s3 api upload function and a zero byte file ends up on s3 (@Radar155 and @gabo) - I also had this problem.

Create a second PassThrough stream and just pipe all data from the first to the second and pass the reference to that second to s3.  You can do this in a couple of different ways - possibly a dirty way is to listen for the "data" event on the first stream and then write that same data to the second stream - the similarly for the "end" event - just call the end function on the second stream.  I've no idea whether this is a bug in the aws api, the version of node or some other issue - but it worked around the issue for me.

Here is how it might look:

```
var PassThroughStream = require('stream').PassThrough;
var srcStream = new PassThroughStream();

var rstream = fs.createReadStream('Learning/stocktest.json');
var sameStream = rstream.pipe(srcStream);
// interesting note: (srcStream == sameStream) at this point
var destStream = new PassThroughStream();
// call your s3.upload function here - passing in the destStream as the Body parameter
srcStream.on('data', function (chunk) {
    destStream.write(chunk);
});

srcStream.on('end', function () {
    dataStream.end();
});
```

Comment: This actually worked for me aswell. The S3 upload function did just "die" silently whenever a multipart upload was used, but when using your solution it worked fine (!). Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you give some info on why the second stream is needed?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using AWS node SDK v3 there is dedicated module for uploading streams/blobs/buffers.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/lib-storage

Answer (score 3):

Create a `new stream.PassThrough()` and `pipe` the input stream to it, then pass the passthrough instance to the body.

Check the following example:

```js
function upload(s3, inputStream) {
    const pass = new PassThrough();

    inputStream.pipe(pass);

    return s3.upload(
        {
            Bucket: 'bucket name',
            Key: 'unique file name',
            Body: pass,
        },
        {
            queueSize: 4, // default concurrency
        },
    ).promise()
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using KnexJS and had a problem using their streaming API. I finally fixed it, hopefully the following will help someone.

```
const knexStream = knex.select('*').from('my_table').stream();
const passThroughStream = new stream.PassThrough();

knexStream.on('data', (chunk) => passThroughStream.write(JSON.stringify(chunk) + '\n'));
knexStream.on('end', () => passThroughStream.end());

const uploadResult = await s3
  .upload({
    Bucket: 'my-bucket',
    Key: 'stream-test.txt',
    Body: passThroughStream
  })
  .promise();
```

Answer (score -5):

If you know the size of the stream you can use [minio-js](http://github.com/minio/minio-js) to upload the stream like this:

```
  s3Client.putObject('my-bucketname', 'my-objectname.ogg', stream, size, 'audio/ogg', function(e) {
    if (e) {
      return console.log(e)
    }
    console.log("Successfully uploaded the stream")
  })
```