# Amazon S3 Remote File Upload with Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, file-upload, npm

I am trying to write a function that would:

1. Take a remote URL as a parameter,
2. Get the file using axios
3. Upload the stream to amazon s3
4. And finally, return the uploaded url

I found help [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37366093/450733). So far, I have this:

```
/* 
 * Method to pipe the stream 
 */
const uploadFromStream = (file_name, content_type) => {
  const pass = new stream.PassThrough();

  const obj_key = generateObjKey(file_name);
  const params = { Bucket: config.bucket, ACL: config.acl, Key: obj_key, ContentType: content_type, Body: pass };

  s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
    if(!err){
        return data.Location;
    } else {
        console.log(err, data);
    }
  });

  return pass;
}


/*
 * Method to upload remote file to s3
 */
const uploadRemoteFileToS3 = async (remoteAddr) => {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: remoteAddr,
        responseType: 'stream'
    }).then( (response) => {
        if(response.status===200){
            const file_name = remoteAddr.substring(remoteAddr.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            const content_type = response.headers['content-type'];
            response.data.pipe(uploadFromStream(file_name, content_type));
        }
    });
}
```

But `uploadRemoteFileToS3` does not return anything (because it's a asynchronous function). How can I get the uploaded url?

**UPDATE**

I have further improved upon the code and wrote a class. Here is what I have now:

```
const config = require('../config.json');

const stream = require('stream');
const axios = require('axios');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

class S3RemoteUploader {
    constructor(remoteAddr){
        this.remoteAddr = remoteAddr;
        this.stream = stream;
        this.axios = axios;
        this.config = config;
        this.AWS = AWS;
        this.AWS.config.update({
            accessKeyId: this.config.api_key,
            secretAccessKey: this.config.api_secret
        });
        this.spacesEndpoint = new this.AWS.Endpoint(this.config.endpoint);
        this.s3 = new this.AWS.S3({endpoint: this.spacesEndpoint});

        this.file_name = this.remoteAddr.substring(this.remoteAddr.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        this.obj_key = this.config.subfolder+'/'+this.file_name;
        this.content_type = 'application/octet-stream';

        this.uploadStream();
    }

    uploadStream(){
        const pass = new this.stream.PassThrough();
        this.promise = this.s3.upload({
            Bucket: this.config.bucket,
            Key: this.obj_key,
            ACL: this.config.acl,
            Body: pass,
            ContentType: this.content_type
        }).promise();
        return pass;
    }

    initiateAxiosCall() {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: this.remoteAddr,
            responseType: 'stream'
        }).then( (response) => {
            if(response.status===200){
                this.content_type = response.headers['content-type'];
                response.data.pipe(this.uploadStream());
            }
        });
    }

    dispatch() {
        this.initiateAxiosCall();
    }

    async finish(){
        //console.log(this.promise); /* return Promise { Pending } */
        return this.promise.then( (r) => {
            console.log(r.Location);
            return r.Location;
        }).catch( (e)=>{
            console.log(e);
        });
    }

    run() {
        this.dispatch();
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

But still have no clue how to catch the result when the promise is resolved. So far, I tried these:

```
testUpload = new S3RemoteUploader('https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/41177');
testUpload.run();
//console.log(testUpload.promise); /* Returns Promise { Pending } */
testUpload.promise.then(r => console.log); // does nothing
```

But none of the above works. I have a feeling I am missing something very subtle. Any clue, anyone?

Comment: it's the `https://address-to-your-s3-bucket + path-of-file`. If your ACL is public read, this url will work well. Path of file is the `Key` here

Comment: This is pretty old, but I'm seeing that your async/promise-calling methods don't return anything. For example, in your `run` method, you call `dispatch` but there is no `await` there. So much of this just becomes "fire and forget". Anywho, the bones of what you have here I do find very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After an upload you can call the getsignedurl function in s3 sdk to get the url where you can also specify the expiry of the url as well. You need to pass the key for that function. Now travelling will update with example later.

> To generate a simple pre-signed URL that allows any user to view the
>   contents of a private object in a bucket you own, you can use the
>   following call to getSignedUrl():

```
 var s3 = new AWS.S3(); 
 var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myKey'}; 
 s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {  
   console.log("The URL is", url); 
 });
```

Official documentation link
http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html

Code must be something like this

```
function uploadFileToS3AndGenerateUrl(cb) {
const pass = new stream.PassThrough();//I have generated streams from file. Using this since this is what you have used. Must be a valid one.
var params = {
            Bucket: "your-bucket", // required
            Key: key , // required
            Body: pass,
            ContentType: 'your content type',

        };
s3.upload(params, function(s3Err, data) {
    if (s3Err) {
        cb(s3Err)
    }
    console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`)

    const params = {
        Bucket: 'your-bucket',
        Key: data.key,
        Expires: 180
    };
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, (urlErr, urlData) => {
        if (urlErr) {

            console.log('There was an error getting your files: ' + urlErr);
            cb(urlErr);

        } else {
            console.log(`url: ${urlData}`);
            cb(null, urlData);

        }
    })
})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In order to use getsignedurl I need to confirm that the upload has finished. Could you please look into the code and guide me where I can check if the upload has finished?

Comment: Also, getsignedurl gives an url that will expire after a given interval. I don't want that. I want a url without an expiry

Comment: You can't have both error and data at the same time. You can confirm the upload success if you get the data. There will be key in the data which you need to pass as the input for getsignedurl function.

Comment: Hmm. Still doesn't solve the async issue I mentioned. I will always get `undefined`. There's no way to return a `promise`

Comment: Setting expiry is optional I just mentioned if you want you can use it.

Comment: `Expiry` has a default of 15 minutes. If you don't manually set `Expiry`, it defaults to 15 mins

Comment: Updated the code. This code is working but not finalized one since it is part of some long process which I use so might need more testing. I have taken what is relevant to the question.

Comment: Thank you so much for the efforts. But I must remind you that I want it to work with axios. This code doesn't work with axios since axios is piping the data and you _must_ return `pass`. I am sorry I am asking a lot (esp since you are on the move right now.) But I do appreciate the efforts. Thanks again!

Comment: I haven't used it. I always try to use official sdks whenever possible.

Comment: axios is a js library that makes remote calls. Much like `request` module

Comment: Is there any special reason for using it rather than using the official sdk?

Comment: The official sdk does not support remote url upload. So I am making a call (via axios) to a remote url and passing the stream to s3.upload

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180584/discussion-between-krishnadas-pc-and-abhisek).

Answer (score 0):

Please check i have update your code might its help you.

```
    /*
         * Method to upload remote file to s3
         */
        const uploadRemoteFileToS3 = async (remoteAddr) => {
            const response = await axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: remoteAddr,
                responseType: 'stream'
            })
               if(response.status===200){
                    const file_name = remoteAddr.substring(remoteAddr.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                    const content_type = response.headers['content-type'];
                    response.data.pipe(uploadFromStream(file_name, content_type));
                }
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    response.data.on('end', (response) => {
                      console.log(response)
                      resolve(response)
                    })

                    response.data.on('error', () => {
                      console.log(response);
                      reject(response)
                    })
              })
        };

       * 
     * Method to pipe the stream 
     */
    const uploadFromStream = (file_name, content_type) => {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const pass = new stream.PassThrough();
          const obj_key = generateObjKey(file_name);
          const params = { Bucket: config.bucket, ACL: config.acl, Key: obj_key, ContentType: content_type, Body: pass };
          s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
            if(!err){
                console.log(data)
                return resolve(data.Location);
            } else {
                console.log(err)
                return reject(err);
            }
          });
       });
    }

//call uploadRemoteFileToS3
    uploadRemoteFileToS3(remoteAddr)
      .then((finalResponse) => {
            console.log(finalResponse)
       })
       .catch((err) => {
         console.log(err);
    });
```