# Unable to decompress gzipped files after uploading input stream chunks in S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, gzip

I'd like to take my input stream and upload gzipped parts to s3 in a similar fashion to the multipart uploader.
However, I want to store the individual file parts in S3 and not turn the parts into a single file.

To do so, I have created the following methods.
But, when I try to gzip decompress each part gzip throws an error and says: `gzip: file_part_2.log.gz: not in gzip format`.

I'm not sure if I am compressing each part correctly?

If I re-initialise the gzipoutputstream: `gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);` and set `gzip.finish()` after reseting the byte array output stream `baos.reset();` then I am able to decompress each part. Not sure why I need todo this, is there a similar `reset` for the gzipoutputstream?

```
public void upload(String bucket, String key, InputStream is, int partSize) throws Exception
{
    String row;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, ENCODING));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);

    int partCounter = 0;
    int lineCounter = 0;
    while ((row = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (baos.size() >= partSize) {
            partCounter = this.uploadChunk(bucket, key, baos, partCounter);

            baos.reset();
        }else if(!row.equals("")){
            row += '\n';
            gzip.write(row.getBytes(ENCODING));
            lineCounter++;
        }
    }

    gzip.finish();
    br.close();
    baos.close();

    if(lineCounter == 0){
        throw new Exception("Aborting upload, file contents is empty!");
    }

    //Final chunk
    if (baos.size() > 0) {
        this.uploadChunk(bucket, key, baos, partCounter);
    }
}

private int uploadChunk(String bucket, String key, ByteArrayOutputStream baos, int partCounter)
{
    ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata();
    metaData.setContentLength(baos.size());

    String[] path = key.split("/");
    String[] filename = path[path.length-1].split("\\.");

    filename[0] = filename[0]+"_part_"+partCounter;

    path[path.length-1] = String.join(".", filename);

    amazonS3.putObject(
            bucket,
            String.join("/", path),
            new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()),
            metaData
    );

    log.info("Upload chunk {}, size: {}", partCounter, baos.size());

    return partCounter+1;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am compressing each part correctly?

Comment: And I dont understand why you gzip the file before uploading? This seems not relevant with your problem/question.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336050/pipe-a-stream-to-s3-upload/37366093 

(you can pass a stream directly to `s3.upload` )

Comment: This is part of an ETL pipeline, chunking the file here lets me do parallel processing in downstream services. The question here is to do with gzip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a single `GZipOutputStream` for all chunks. So you're actually writing pieces of a GZipped file, which would have to be recombined to be useful.

Making the minimal change to your existing code:

```
if (baos.size() >= partSize) {
    gzip.close(); 
    partCounter = this.uploadChunk(bucket, key, baos, partCounter);
    baos = baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
}
```

You need to do the same at the end of the loop. Also, you shouldn't throw an exception if the line counter is 0: it's entirely possible that the file is exactly divisible into a set number of chunks.

To improve the code, I would wrap the `GZIPOutputStream` in an `OutputStreamWriter` and a `BufferedWriter`, so that you don't need to do the string-bytes conversion explicitly.

And lastly, don't use `ByteArrayOutputStream.reset()`. It doesn't save you anything over just creating a new stream, and opens the door for errors if you ever forget to reset.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer!