# dest.on is not a function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream, next.js13

I trying to upload some pdf to s3 and then combain all the uploded pdf to a zip File

```
  async genPdfStep1(data: any, type: string, pdfId: any) {
        let keys = []
        let imageData: any
        if (data[0]?.customImage) {
            imageData = await this.getImage(`https://${process.env.AWS_BUCKET1_NAME}.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/${data[0]?.customImage}`)
        }
        for await (const element of data) {
            const pdfBuffer = await this.genPdfStep2(element, type, imageData)
            const random = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000)
            const s3key = await this.s3.uploadPdf(`${element.candidateId}_report-${type}_${random}.pdf`, pdfBuffer, 'application/pdf')
            keys.push(s3key)
        }
        const S3ClientConfig = {
            credentials: {
                accessKeyId: this.config.get(Configuration.AWS_ACCESS_KEY),
                secretAccessKey: this.config.get(Configuration.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY),
            },
            region: this.config.get(Configuration.REGION),
        };

        const s3: any = new AWS.S3Client(S3ClientConfig)
        const bucketName = this.config.get(Configuration.AWS_BUCKET2_NAME);
        const archiver = require('archiver');
        const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 } });

        const uploadFromStream = async (s3: any) => {
            const pass = new stream.PassThrough()

            const archiveName = `${type}_${moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")}_${momenttz().tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('H.m')}.zip`;
            const params = {
                Bucket: this.config.get(Configuration.AWS_BUCKET2_NAME),
                Key: archiveName,
                Body: pass,
                ContentType: 'application/zip'
            };
            try {
                const parallelUploads3 = new Upload({
                    client: new AWS.S3(),
                    tags: [], // optional tags
                    queueSize: 4, // optional concurrency configuration
                    leavePartsOnError: false, // optional manually handle dropped parts
                    params: params,
                });
                parallelUploads3.on("httpUploadProgress", (progress) => {
                    console.log(progress);
                });

                await parallelUploads3.done();
                ;
                await this.bulkPdfStatusModel.updateOne({ _id: pdfId }, {
                    s3link: `https://report-zip.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/${archiveName}`,
                    pdfStatus: 'ready to download',
                    pdfName: archiveName
                });
            } catch (err) {
                throw err;
            }


            return pass;

        }

        // response.set({
        //     'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
        //     'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="${archiveName}.zip"`
        //   })
        // archive.pipe(response);

        archive.pipe(uploadFromStream(s3))

        for await (const key of keys) {
            const params = { Bucket: bucketName, Key: key };
            const s3Stream = await s3.send(new AWS.GetObjectCommand(params))
            archive.append(s3Stream.Body, { name: key });
        };
        archive.finalize()
        return true
    }
```

While runing this function this error is throwing:

```
C:\Users\Hp\OneDrive\Desktop\Wit quest\wq-reports\node_modules\archiver\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:584
  dest.on('unpipe', onunpipe);
       ^
TypeError: dest.on is not a function
    at Archiver.Readable.pipe (C:\Users\Hp\OneDrive\Desktop\Wit quest\wq-reports\node_modules\archiver\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:584:8)
    at EvaluationService.genPdfStep1 (C:\Users\Hp\OneDrive\Desktop\Wit quest\wq-reports\src\evaluation\evaluation.service.ts:1960:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

the line tha saying the error is occuring is this line

`archive.pipe(uploadFromStream(s3))`

I have tryed to upload some pdf to s3 and then i have tryed to zip the uploded pdfs and then upload the zip file to s3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. FYI, the first question in the "Related questions" section below is [NodeJS piping data to AWS S3 TypeError: dest.on is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63368388), which appears to be quite closely related to your question.