# NodeJs Upload csv string content to s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have tried to upload csv  content data to s3 but its some how not working
Below My code to store csv data into csv.gz file

```
var filename= "ff1.csv.gz"
var csvData = "username,email,year,month\n"
csvData = csvData + username +","+email+","+year_data+","+month_data+"\n"

var paramsu = {
    Bucket: bucket1,
    Key: filename,
    Body: csvData,
    ContentType: 'application/octet-stream'

  };


var res = await s3.putObject(paramsu).promise();
```

It is showing  corrupted gzfile not able to extract

Any help would really save my day

Comment: Where are you converting the file into a gzip? This only seems to upload csv file as `ff1.csv.gz`

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have the file ready, you can create a writestream and use it to pass to s3 sdk.

The question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50291380/2688699

Answer (score 0):

WE can Upload IMAGE/ CSV/ EXCEL files to AWS s3 using multer-s3.

Im using **.single(fieldname)** method for uploading single file.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

const s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    region: process.env.REGION,
});

 const upload = multer({
   storage: multerS3({
     s3: s3,
     bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET,
     metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
       cb(null, {fieldName: 'Meta_Data'});
     },
     key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
     },
     limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5 //  allowed only 5 MB files
    }
   })
 }).single('file');
 
exports.uploadfile = async(req,res,next)=>{
   try{ 
         upload(req,res, function(err){
             if(err){
                 console.log(err);
             }
             console.log(req.file.location);    
   })
})
}catch (err){
   res.status(400).json({
       status : 'fail', 
       message : err.message
   });
}
}
```

In Routes file

```
router.route('/')
      .post(imageController.uploadfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to mention the ContentType to be `text/csv` and pass the Body as a simple string like below. Just make sure the string is formatted as a csv.

```
await s3Client.putObject({
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: 'myFile.csv',
  ContentType:'text/csv',
  Body: "username,password\nuser1,pass1\nuser2,pass2\n"
}).promise();
```