# Export an array from NodeJS directly to amazon S3 without first saving it locally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku

This is the working flow of my application:

1. Get the data from sources.
2. Perform some operations.
3. Save the data on a csv file created locally.
4. After the completion, upload the csv to S3 and delete the local file.

However, when I tried to deploy this application in heroku, I get an error in `writeFileSync` and cannot create files. To tackle that, I want to store the csv values in a nested array, and then upload directly to S3 as a csv file without local interference.

How do I achieve this? If there are better approaches, please do mention.

Comment: How are you currently creating your CSV file locally? Please show us the code.

Comment: @Chris I am just using fs.createWriteStream(loc) for an stream and writing data to the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write strings directly to S3 using the AWS SDK's [putObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) method.

The Body parameter can be one of:

- Buffer
- string value
- stream

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. Can you also help me to for setting up writeStreams directly to S3? Any tutorials or stackoverflow answers?

Comment: There are a couple of streaming example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336050/pipe-a-stream-to-s3-upload).